Android Resource Linking Failed: android:attr/lStar Not Found with external_app_launcher
I'm facing a build issue in my Flutter project when using the external_app_launcher package. The build fails with the following error:
Execution failed for task ':external_app_launcher:verifyReleaseResources'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
Android resource linking failed
ERROR: C:\Users\erenium\IdeaProjects\pecs_app\build\external_app_launcher\intermediates\merged_res\release\values\values.xml:194: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

Flutter Version: 3.24.0
Android SDK Version: 34
in my gradle files :
compileSdkVersion 34
minSdk = 21
kotlin version = 2.0.0

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

--workaround
Go to the android studio external libraries in the left side
--> select the library external_app_launcher
--> then goto the android -> build.gradle and update the compileSdkVersion to 34
